# Extension method to exclude records whose id exists anywhere in another field

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I have a requirement to get the data from a table.

This is the structure of the table:

```
ID      PackageID     DESC  OriginalPackageID    Status
-------------------------------------------------------
1          00A        Test        Null             P

2          00B        xxxx        Null             P

3          00A        test1        1               W
```

I want to write a linq query using the extension method to fetch the records with `Status` = `P` but whose `ID` doesn't exist in any of the records' `OriginalPackageID`.

For example, the record with `ID` = 1 has `Status` = `P`, but 1 is the third record's `OriginalPackageID`. So the first record should be excluded. Only the second record should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

So you want all records from your table that have a Status equal to P and of which there is not any element in the table that has a value of OriginalPackageId equal to the ID of the record.

This description already says how to do this, although I'm not sure whether it is efficient:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> table = ...
var result = table
    .Where(record => record.Status == P
       && !table.Any(item => item.OriginalPackageId == record.Id));
```

This is not efficient, befause for every record it will potentially have to check the complete table to check that its ID is not used as OriginalPackageId.

Luckily you don't care which record has a value of OriginalPackageId that equals your record's ID. Therefore you don't have to remember which record has this OriginalPackageId value.

You only need to remember that **any record uses this OriginalPackageId value**.

So let's first put the used OriginalPackageIds in a `HashSet<int>` object. This will cost you one pass on the elements of the table:

```
IEnumerable<int> allOriginalPackageIds = table
   .Select(record => record.OriginalPackageId);
HashSet<int> usedPackageIds = new HashSet<int>(allOriginalPackageIds);
```

The constructor of the HashSet will remove duplicates.

Now you can use [HashSet.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx) to lookup if the ID is used in any OriginalPackageID. This is a very fast function.

Your extension function will be like:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyClass> ExtractOriginalItems(
    this IEnumerable<MyClass> table)
{
    IEnumerable<int> allOriginalPackageIds = table
       .Select(record => record.OriginalPackageId);
    HashSet<int> usedPackageIds = new HashSet<int>(allOriginalPackageIds);

    foreach(var record in table)
    {
        // return elements with status P and not ID in hashset:
        if (record.Status == P && !usedPackageIds.Contains(record.Id))
        {
            yield return record;
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the HashSet is O(1)
ForEach is O(1)